# (InvalidParameterValueException) when calling the CreateFunction operation: The role defined for the function cannot be assumed by Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-iam

I can't seem to assign an iam role to a lambda function using boto3. Constantly getting an error message:
botocore.errorfactory.InvalidParameterValueException: An error occurred (InvalidParameterValueException) when calling the CreateFunction operation: The role defined for the function cannot be assumed by Lambda.

Here's my simple code:

```
import boto3
import json 

# Boto3 Clients

iam = boto3.client('iam')
client = boto3.client('lambda')
rolename = 'lambda_role2'
inputbucket = 'inputbuckgs'

#Assume policy for role policy 

assumerolepolicy = {
        "Version": "2012-10-17",
        "Statement": [
                        {
                            "Effect": "Allow",
                            "Principal": {
                                "Service": [
                                    "lambda.amazonaws.com"
                                ]
                            },
                            "Action": [
                                "sts:AssumeRole"
                            ]
                        }
        ]
    }

#Creating a role and adding assume role policy 

response_role = iam.create_role(
    RoleName= rolename,
    AssumeRolePolicyDocument= json.dumps(assumerolepolicy),                    
    Description='lambda function for role',
)

# generate role arn 
rolearn = response_role['Role']['Arn']
#Lambda Function

response_lam = client.create_function(
    FunctionName='transcoder-lambda',
    Runtime='python3.7',
    Role = rolearn ,
    Handler='index.handler',
    Code={
        'S3Bucket': inputbucket,
        'S3Key': 'function.zip'
    },
    Description='function to transcode videos'
)
```

any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried creating the function *later* with the role you created?

The role itself seems fine, so I wonder if it's a race condition. AWS IAM is a global service, so I can sometimes take a *little* while (usually ms, but sometimes a little longer). Since your `create_function` call is happening right after the `create_role` call, the role might not have propagated to the Lambda service yet.

Comment: the role gets created fine, it is the function that wouldn't. Wouldn't it give me an error message something like 'role doesn't exist rather than an invalid parameter?

Comment: Good point. Have you output the the `rolearn` to check it is valid? What happens if you try and create the function by hand with that ARN?

Comment: yes, I have tried print(rolearn) before assigning to the function and it seemed to be valid. I am starting to believe this is a boto3 bug rather than something being wrong with the code.